# selectively gzip large files in a directory

Tags: command-line, gzip

I have several directories with files of various sizes. I would like to archive only those files over 100 megabytes in size. Any ideas of a simple command line argument to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
find . -size +100M -exec gzip {} \;
```

If you are thinking of running it regularly, you may wish to exclude already gzipped files like this

```
find . ! -name "*.gz" -size +100M -exec gzip {} \;
```

And if you have lots of big files and (say) a quad core CPU, you could do 4 at a time like this

```
find . -size +100M | xargs -n 1 -P 4 gzip
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `-size` option to the `find` command.

Documentation: [`find(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)